# Can't use inner-query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to simple update query with following syntax:

```
UPDATE cl
SET cl_s="active_"
WHERE id in (
                SELECT distinct 
                    c.id 
                from
                    cl          c,
                    ac          a,
                    cl_ac       ac
                where
                    c.id=ac.cl_id
                    and
                    a.id=ac.ac_id
                    and 
                    c.cl_s="someval"
                    and 
                    a.ac_no !=""
            )
;
```

The error I get is: Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table for update in FROM clause

I've read through posts which mention that MySQL is unable to run query like this. I'd want to know a seamless way to restructure such queries to a structure which works. The solution seems to be using joins instead but I can't seem to grasp the concept.

A pseudo code would be helpful, to help with the understanding. Something like

```
(Main query)
where var in (subquery generating var list)
```

to

```
(main query) inner join (subquery generating var list) on var ???
```

Comment: first step: move away from implicit joins to explicit join

Comment: You should use explicit joins, also you should use naming standards. What is `cl.cl_s`?

Comment: `ac.ac_no`... You'll keep running into issues that are difficult to solve with names like these!

Comment: @dustytrash the reason for those silly names is that I didn't want to throw away actual names in a public forum.

Barmar, I guess you didn't even read my question. I did mention that I've gone through the examples already. I didn't even request for a query - to understand the concept than just getting the dish served readily. I want to learn the reason for such structure with MySQL.

Comment: @SushantVasishta In that case I don't recommend using your SIN/SSN or other private information as a table/column name!

Comment: Like I said, the pseudo names were used for a reason. And no, they weren't SIN/SSN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JOIN in [UPDATE statements in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html)

```
UPDATE cl
JOIN cl_ac ON cl.id = cl_ac.cl_id
JOIN ac ON cl_ac.ac_id = ac.id
SET cl.cl_s = 'active_'
WHERE cl.cl_s = 'someval' AND ac.ac_no != ''
```

PS: Use single-quotes for string literals and date literals in SQL. Double-quotes may be used for delimited identifiers, depending on the [sql_mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html).